Why can't I use 'PUT' in Express.js? Every time I send data to the API, it shows undefined
This the updating router part of the route '/parts'
// Update a part
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("data got",req.body);
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.query(
            'UPDATE partimages SET partname = ?, description = ?, company = ? WHERE id = ?',
            [   
                req.body.partname, req.body.description, req.body.company, req.params.id
            ]);

        res.json(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

I am sending data from this function:
function UpdatePartfunc(formData, id) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/parts/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
}
var id = '6';

const formData = {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Test Part',
    description: 'This is a test part',
    company: 'Test Company',
};

UpdatePartfunc(formData, id);


I am trying to send the formdata from the frontend UpdatePartfunc to the API so that it can update the table data using the id.
Log of the API:
Listening at http://localhost:3000
data got: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'partname')

Log of Frontend function:
PUT http://localhost:3000/parts/6 500 (Internal Server Error)
UpdatePartfunc @ try.js:2
(anonymous) @ App.jsx:14
VM9480:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', "Server Error" is not valid JSON


Are you sure that uri inside PUT router.put('/:id', is correct while you are fetch url is http://localhost:3000/parts/${id} ?

I see two issues with your code, the first being that in your route, you use req.body.partname while the provided formData only has name.
The second one is that you need to stringify your body in your fetch() call :
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/parts/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
}).then(...);

This should solve your undefined body problem.
